# "Failed to replace env in config: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}"

Tags: authentication, github, environment-variables, token, account

I have error to run yarn or other comand.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}".
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzFuc.png)

when I enter the token everything works but when I reopen visual studio code I have to enter the token again.

Can you help thanks